# SQL Server how to populate data to table2 when table1 updated

Tags: sql-server

I'm creating a table to store cars, and another table to store the time when the new car was added to the database, can someone please explain to me how to create the relationship to update time automatically when the car was created.

```
Create table Cars
(
        CarID int Primary Key identity(1,1),
        Make varchar(50),
        Model varchar(50),
        Colour varchar(59)
)

create Table TimeLogs
(
    AddedOn SYSDATETIME(),
    CarId int unique foreign key references Cars(CarId)
)
```

Comment: You can't add the same car more than once so this would be a 1:1 relationship right? Why do you need a separate table for what should be a column in the Cars table?

Comment: @SeanLange I believe that he would like to have history

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - History of what? It is only the time of insert that is being captured. This can't happen more than once.

Comment: ohh, yes. Sorry, he asked for INSERTS.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this by not using a second table for what should be a column in the Cars table. The table would be designed more appropriately like this.

```
Create table Cars
    (
        CarID int Primary Key identity(1,1),
        Make varchar(50),
        Model varchar(50),
        Colour varchar(59),
        AddedOn datetime default SYSDATETIME()
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

To automatically update one table whenever another table is updated, you need to use a [TRIGGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Just wanted to create an answer, however Tab Alleman was quicker. Just want to add that using TRIGGERs is not good practice. You can use it, however the better way would be to add INSERT statement in the place where there this record was actually updated (stored procedure, application code, etc).

Answer (score -1):

You needs to use insert trigger for the same, as below

CREATE TRIGGER yourNewTrigger ON yourSourcetable
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO yourDestinationTable
        (col1, col2    , col3, user_id, user_name)
    SELECT
        'a'  , default , null, user_id, user_name
        FROM inserted

go